# Chrome Extension downloading resource tt_chain_token 403

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have built an extension for google chrome from which I want to download videos from tik tok, in such a way. I have added a button for each video and from this button I want to download the video. But when I click this button, the video is downloaded, but also in the console I get such an error:

```
GET https://v16-webapp-prime.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0037c001-aiso/oYe1nbY3ID3eEIS7SQIgeEjrIxjoAXfilGlDmy/?a=1988&ch=0&cr=0&dr=0&lr=unwatermarked&cd=0%7C0%7C0%7C0&cv=1&br=972&bt=486&cs=0&ds=6&ft=_RwJrB0Vq8Zmoa2Kwc_vjjDP8AhLrus&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=OmlpZjRnNTs5PDwzMzU0N0BpM3VnbmY6ZmduazMzZjczM0BjYDIzLy8xXi4xLzZfXzUvYSNlc2IxcjRvY2lgLS1kMWNzcw%3D%3D&btag=e00080000&expire=1688521036&l=202307041936199D4020C697440F3CB2FF&ply_type=2&policy=2&signature=0304ff4339bac2a8a762555526ed6ec7&tk=tt_chain_token 403
downloadVideo @ downloadVideo.js:31
(anonymous) @ downloadVideo.js:22
```

After this error, the video is downloaded but does not open, the player says wrong format

This is the code i have added on `downloadVideo.js`

```
// Video download function

// Add download video icon
function addVideoDownload() {
    // Get Video Elemet
    const videoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tiktok-1soki6-DivItemContainerForSearch');
    videoElements.forEach(function (video) {
      const downloadButton = document.createElement('a');
      downloadButton.href = '#';
      downloadButton.classList.add('download-video-button');
      downloadButton.innerHTML = '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Circle-icons-download.svg/1200px-Circle-icons-download.svg.png" alt="Download">';
  
      // Handle click event to trigger the download
      downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
  
        // Get the video URL
        const videoUrl = video.querySelector('video').src;
  
        // Trigger the download
        downloadVideo(videoUrl);
      });
  
      // Append the download button to the video container
      video.appendChild(downloadButton);
    });
  
    // Function to download the video
    function downloadVideo(url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          // Create a temporary link element
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.download = 'video.mp4'; // Set the desired filename
          link.type = 'video/mp4'; // Set the MIME type explicitly
  
          // Trigger the download
          link.click();
  
          // Clean up
          URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error downloading the video:', error);
        });
    }
}

// Function to observe DOM changes
function observeDOMChangesDownloadButton() {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList' || mutation.type === 'subtree') {
                // addVideoDownload();
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
    });
}

// Add link element an initial window load
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setTimeout(addVideoDownload, 1000);
})

// Observe DOM changes
observeDOMChangesDownloadButton();
```

Any idea how to make this to work?

Comment: The method you're using to download files is... interesting. Where did you find it? Does it really work?

Comment: Some by myself, and some with help of gpt but i see sometimes gpt does not work very good couse still le logic is mine. But why you think is interesign? ... can you help me to fix this?

Comment: This is a standard web way to download files. Thing is, the `src` of video element is probably a blob: URL, which has already expired. Use a binary viewer to inspect the contents of the file.

Comment: > Use a binary viewer to inspect the contents of the file.   I really does not know how to make this. Can you help me for this?

Comment: Hello, I'm still trying to solve this problem but I couldn't. can someone give me an idea?